# writing new image data to a file after converting to grayscale php

Tags: php

Im using the following code to take an image, convert it to grayscale, and then save the grayscale image:

```
$imagename = "$imagename"; // path to previously uploaded color jpeg

        $im = ImageCreateFromJpeg($imagename);

    $imgw = imagesx($im);
    $imgh = imagesy($im);

    for ($i=0; $i<$imgw; $i++)
    {
            for ($j=0; $j<$imgh; $j++)
            {

                    $rgb = ImageColorAt($im, $i, $j);

                    $rr = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
                    $gg = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
                    $bb = $rgb & 0xFF;

                    $g = round(($rr + $gg + $bb) / 3);

                    $val = imagecolorallocate($im, $g, $g, $g);

                    imagesetpixel ($im, $i, $j, $val);
            }
    }

    $grayimgpath = "step2cache/".$saltname."_gray.jpg"; //$saltname is a randomly generated image name



$fh = fopen($grayimgpath, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $im);
fclose($fh);
```

The problem is, when i access this file, its blank, 15 bytes.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to write to the file an image handle not actual image data. Try this:

```
imagejpeg($im, $grayimgpath);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't just write image object to a file. There are functions in GD library for that. So instead of `fopen` and `fwrite`, you should use [`imagejpeg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) with filename in second parameter:

```
imagejpeg($im, $grayimgpath);
```

Comment: `$im` is not a binary content of a file, it is an PHP object containing some internal structure defined by GD. When you write it to the file, you write its textual representation, probably the same as `(string) $im`.